# what is the proper way to build/stack virtual inheritance constructors

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

I am writing a GUI sketch for the esp32 on the Arduino IDE.
My constructor for the usable classes are getting very long, cumbersome to write and keep correct.
So I started stacking #define statements to keep my code easy to read

For each abstract class I write 3 #define statements.

<class_name>_PRAM list the varable type and name.
<class_name>_USE  writes the varable list for use in constructors
<class_name>_CALL writes the constructor section for classes which inhearet from this class

My question is, What is the proper way to deal with this type of problem?
Would this solution be considered good practice?.

**Below is a long summery and a code snippets.**
The classes for my gui objects are all built off a base class I named "DIALOG_OBJECT".
Each has a set of values orgin_x, orgin_y, width, height, and a virtual Draw() method.

There are virtual class built on top of the base class such as
button, text_button, listbox, which implement the Draw() method, but introduce
virtual onClick() method and additional variables.

Then from there I have built the usable classes that receive input from the user via touch screen.
For example BUTTON_INPUT_STRING, and BUTTON_INPUT_FLOAT, which require addition variables.

by stacking #define statements for each virtual class I have made my code smaller and readable but difficult to addend.

The final usage I want is as follows

Edit: I chose a different dialog class which better shows my desired usage

```
//This button closes the dialog that clicked it.
class DIALOG_BUTTON_CLOSE_DIALOG: public DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT{
  public:
  DIALOG_BUTTON_CLOSE_DIALOG (_DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT_PRAM) : _DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT_CALL{};
  void onClick(DIALOG* d){
    d->gui->removeDialog(d);
  }
};
//This listbox copys the value of the selected item to a char[]
class network_listbox: public DIALOG_LISTBOX{
  public:
    network_listbox( _DIALOG_LISTBOX_PRAM ):_DIALOG_LISTBOX_CALL{}
    
    void onClick(DIALOG* p){
      strncpy( config_file.ssid, content[selection].c_str(), sizeof(config_file.ssid));
    }

};
//Button will display "Connect", "Connecting", "Disconnect", or "bad password" depending on the system state
class WIFI_CONNECT_BUTTON: public DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT{
  public:
    bool connecting = false;
  void onClick(DIALOG* d){
    if( is_wifi_connected ){
      try_to_connect_to_wifi = false;
      connecting = false;
      WiFi.disconnect();
      string = "Connect";
      Draw(0);
    }else{
      try_to_connect_to_wifi = true;
      string = "Connecting";
      connecting = true;
      Draw(0);
    }
 };       
};

class WIFI_DIALOG: public DIALOG{
  public:
    EVENT_RETURN Event_handle(EVENT_QUEUE e);
    //object type              name         X   Y    Len  Heigh  color 1      color 2         prefix text  text size   text color  variable

    DIALOG_BUTTON_CLOSE_DIALOG CLOSE{          0, 160, 150,  40, ILI9341_BLUE     , ILI9341_PINK,     "Back"   , 2, 0xFFFF};
    network_listbox        NETWORKLIST{        0,   0, 150, 150, ILI9341_DARKGREEN, ILI9341_BLUE, 2};
    DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_CHAR   SSID{         155,   0, 160,  40, ILI9341_DARKGREEN, ILI9341_BLUE, "SSID:\n",     2, 0xFFFF, config_file.ssid, sizeof(config_file.ssid)};
    DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_CHAR   PASS{         155,  50, 160,  40, ILI9341_DARKGREEN, ILI9341_BLUE, "Password:\n\n\n", 2, 0xFFFF, config_file.pass, sizeof(config_file.pass)};
    WIFI_CONNECT_BUTTON     CONNECT{         155, 100, 160,  40, ILI9341_DARKGREEN, ILI9341_BLUE, is_wifi_connected?(char*)"Disconnect":try_to_connect_to_wifi?(char*)"Connecting":(char*)"Connect", 2, 0xFFFF};
    DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_BOOL     AUTOCONNECT{155, 150, 160,  40, ILI9341_DARKGREEN, ILI9341_BLUE, "Auto Connect\n", 2, 0xFFFF, &config_file.autoconnect_to_wifi};
    TaskHandle_t ScanTaskHandle = NULL;    
};
```

the way I build my classes is as follows

```
//base class for dialog objects
#define _DIALOG_OBJECT_PRAM uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h
#define _DIALOG_OBJECT_USE  x,y,w,h
#define _DIALOG_OBJECT_CALL DIALOG_OBJECT{_DIALOG_OBJECT_USE}
class DIALOG_OBJECT{
  public:
    DIALOG_OBJECT( _DIALOG_OBJECT_PRAM ):orgin_x{x}, orgin_y{y}, length{w}, height{h},update_flag{0}, img{0}{};
    virtual ~DIALOG_OBJECT();
    virtual void Draw(GFXcanvas16* p)=0;
    ...
};

//base class for interactive objects
#define _DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC_PRAM _DIALOG_OBJECT_PRAM
#define _DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC_USE  _DIALOG_OBJECT_USE
#define _DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC_CALL DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC{_DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC_USE}
class DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC: public DIALOG_OBJECT{
  public:
    DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC( _DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC_PRAM ):
     _DIALOG_OBJECT_CALL {};

    virtual EVENT_RETURN Event_handle(DIALOG* d, EVENT_QUEUE e)=0;
    ...
};

//base class for drawable text
#define _DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT_PRAM char* s, uint8_t t_size, uint16_t color
#define _DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT_USE s, t_size, color
#define _DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT_CALL DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT{_DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT_USE}
class DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT{
  public:
    DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT(_DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT_PRAM) {string = s; text_size = t_size; text_color = color;};
    ...
};

//usable class STATIC TEXT
class DIALOG_TEXT: public DIALOG_OBJECT, public DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT{
  public:
    DIALOG_TEXT(_DIALOG_OBJECT_PRAM, _DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT_PRAM, uint16_t bg_color=0x0000):
      _DIALOG_OBJECT_CALL, _DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT_CALL{ text_background_color = bg_color;};
    ...
};

//abstract push button
#define _DIALOG_BUTTON_PRAM _DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC_PRAM, uint16_t c1, uint16_t c2
#define _DIALOG_BUTTON_USE  _DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC_USE, c1, c2
#define _DIALOG_BUTTON_CALL DIALOG_BUTTON{_DIALOG_BUTTON_USE}
class DIALOG_BUTTON: public DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC{
  public:
    DIALOG_BUTTON( _DIALOG_BUTTON_PRAM ):
        _DIALOG_OBJECT_DYNAMIC_CALL {rollover_color = false; color1 = c1; color2 = c2;};
    ...   
};

//push button with text
#define _DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT_PRAM _DIALOG_BUTTON_PRAM, _DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT_PRAM
#define _DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT_USE  _DIALOG_BUTTON_USE, _DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT_USE
#define _DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT_CALL DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT{_DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT_USE}
class DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT: public DIALOG_BUTTON, public DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT{
  public:
    DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT( _DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT_PRAM ) :
      _DIALOG_BUTTON_CALL, _DIALOG_OBJECT_TEXT_CALL {};
   ...
};


//abstract button with keyboard input
#define _DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_PRAM _DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT_PRAM
#define _DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_USE  _DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT_USE
#define _DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_CALL DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT{_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_USE}
class DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT: public DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT{
  public:
    DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT( _DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_PRAM ): _DIALOG_BUTTON_TEXT_CALL 
    ...
};

class DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_BOOL: public DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT{
  public:
    DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_BOOL (_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_PRAM, bool *val):_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_CALL {value = val;};
    ...
};

class DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_INT: public DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT{
  public:
    DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_INT (_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_PRAM, uint32_t *val):_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_CALL {value = val;charset = NUMBER_KEYBOARD;};
    ...  
};

class DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_DOUBLE: public DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT{
  public:
    DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_DOUBLE (_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_PRAM, double* val):_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_CALL {value = val;charset = NUMBER_KEYBOARD;};
    ...
};

class DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_STRING: public DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT{
  public:
    DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_STRING (_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_PRAM, std::string* val):_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_CALL {value = val;charset = FULL_KEYBOARD;};
  ...
};

class DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_CHAR: public DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT{
  public:
    DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_CHAR (_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_PRAM, char* val, int sz):_DIALOG_BUTTON_INPUT_CALL {value = val; size = sz; charset = FULL_KEYBOARD;};
    ...
```

Comment: Maybe you can try using templates, but I am not 100% sure if this approach will work

Comment: too many arguments is not nice. There are some obvious simplifications you can make. Instead of two integers for `X` and `Y` you can have a single `Point` argument. Instead of two integers for `Len` and `Height` you can have a single `Dimensions`. `prefix text`, `text size` and `text color` can be `TextProperties`. Macros are never a good solution

Comment: Using structure would shorten the number of arguments but make declarations more complex. My question is referring to the definitions of the complex classes.

Comment: I edited the code snippets to better explain my question.

Comment: You might provide a set of mutator methods that all return a handle to "this" to allow function chaining.  Then you can construct your object, then call a bunch of these in one go...  You might also put all your attributes together in a configuration struct object and pass that to your constructor...